# svg.js svg.draggable.js and manipulation of appearance

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I want to use [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/) in to implement drag and drop, and manipulate appearance of graphical elements. It mainly works, but I do not fully understand why.

I have extracted the essential part from my app to  illustrate the situation my app. It is possible to play around there and see the effects.

https://jsfiddle.net/bwl21/ex8dcxtm/12/

The SVG is generated as a string by my application. I simulate this by adding the SVG to the HTML pane in jsfiddle.

I have a function "set_draggable(id) which gets the id of the svg element and attaches a drag handler.

```
function set_draggable(svg_element) {

  var xx = SVG.get(svg_element);
  xx.addClass("zn_draggable");

  xx.draggable(function(x, y) {
    return {
      x:  Math.floor(x),
      y:  Math.floor(y)
    }
  });

  var sx = 0,
    sy = 0;
  xx.on('dragstart', function(e) {
    sx = e.detail.p.x;
    sy = e.detail.p.y;
    this.fill("red");
  });

  // todo: don't know why 'this' is the only way to change the filling ...
  xx.on('dragend', function(e) {
    this.fill("green");
    var result = {
      delta: [ e.detail.p.x - sx, e.detail.p.y - sy],
      element: svg_element
    };
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  })
}


set_draggable("ZN_18");
set_draggable("ZN_19");
set_draggable("ZN_20");
set_draggable("ZN_21");
```

My questions:

1. in the draggable event handlers, I want to change the colors of the object.
   **Why does 'this' refer to the dragged object?** It is the only way I found to apply fill() with an effect. I tried with `xx` which is the dom node I attach the draggable. Also tried with `e.target.fill("red")`.
2. When dragging the Fermata - Character (which is a path), the color does not change. It works when dragging text. **What could be the reason?**

   **Answer by bwl21**: Meanwhile I found that the attributes of the group do not override attributes of the children. So I had to remove stroke and fill from the path.

   Neverheless, I did not manage to navigate to the children and change the attributes there.
3. When dragging ZN_19 it can **move only vertical** as I made the  draggable. If I wrap it in a group (like ZN_20) and call draggable() on this, I can move it around as I wish.
4. **Is there a better way to get the delta as result of drag?** I store x and y in the 'dragstart' handler, and compute the delta in the 'dragend' handler. I wourd expect the delta to be integer number as I round it by the function passed to the draggable().
5. If I have many objects (my app has about 300), will I face a performance issues, as I create many handlers? Is there a better way to do this.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow thats a bunch of questions. I will try to work them through.

## 1. Why does 'this' refer to the dragged object?

This is something svg.js does in general. All event handler are executed in the context of the element.
So this prints `true` when clicking on the element:

```
el.on('click', function() { console.log(this == el) })
```

So yes, you *can* use `xx` instead and its working just fine in your example. Just replace `this` with `xx`.

However, `this` is the save way because you can run into trouble with variable scoping when using an outer variable which might be redecleared somewhere else (typical example: attaching event handler in a  loop)

## 2. Why the fill of the fermata does not change

This is already correctly answered. As a general tip I can say: Dont use groups if they only hold one shape. There is no need to do so.

For the follow up question about navigating through the dom: svg.js has a wonderful documentation. Just type `children` into the search at http://svgjs.dev/.

You have multiple possibilities:

```
el.children() // array
el.get(index) // element at index
el.first() // first element
el.last() // last element
```

## 3. Why is dragging of text only working vertically

Your svg was not generated using svg.js. Svg.js treats every first level tspan as a new line **IF** it was created with svg.js. If not, it does nothing special with it. In your case that means: The text **IS** moved (look into the dom - you can see it). However, in your svg code you reset the x-coordinate to `80` in the tspan so it stays there forever. If you dont want that, dont use `x` but instead use `dx` or call `newLine()` on the tspan which will enable the special handling for lines which also includes changes to the x coordinate when the texts x coordinate is changed.

A note on this: I did that in your example fiddle which made the text disappear. Thats because the text itself has an x of 189 which is out of the screen so you need to adjust that to 80 first

## 4. Is there a better way to get the delta as result of drag?

No there isnt.

Rounding is applied to the coordinates just before setting them on the element. However: The orginal point is given in the event object because its the source of truth

## 5. Are there performance issues when using many elements

Lots of elements slow down dom operations. So dont move hundreds of elements together. Just applying handlers to them shouldnt be a problem.

However, performance also depends on the browser. Try to write performant code. Reuse the draggable-constraint function by defining them (`el.draggable(nameOfFunc)`), try to avoid accessing outer variables (like `xx`) in the handler so no closure needs to be generated, dont do heavy work on drag, use dragend instead to do the heavy lifting.

Hope I could help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It really helps a lot. I add separate comments for the details,

Comment: WRT 2. I did not manage to made the path move along with the cursor without wrapping it in a group. The path data is not in the final coordinates, so I have to transform it. I saw the navigation methods but did not manage to change the attributes. I will try again. Meanwhile, I have a working solution by removing the attributes from the path. I also now have a handle in the group to make it easier to to catch it with the mouse.

Comment: WRT 3: The svg is generated outside of svg.js because I did not find the library early enough. And I plan to move the SVG-genrator to a webworker which has no access to the DOM. Generating the SVG as a string was pretty easy. I also have the problem, that the SVG must look the same as the PDF I create with jspdf. So I need to control every line of  text. I tried usig; but it did not work. dx is addes to the end of the previous line. The only way to make it work, was to wrap it in a group and dragging the group.

Comment: WRT4: do you mean that in the event object of the dragend I should find the original (where dragging starts) position? i could not find it.

Comment: WRT 5: as of now I do not have a performance problem. i do not drag 300 Elements around. But thanks for the hints, I will rework the code accordingly, just to be on the safe side. But as I have the start coordinates as outer variables, I am afraid I will stay with with the closure being generated.

Comment: We should discuss this in chat. I will get back to you when I have more time.

Comment: @Bernhard join our support channel on gitter where we can discuss this more deeply: https://gitter.im/svgdotjs/svg.js